# Runtimes not visible in the ibm operations console while connecting app server from the ibm http server

Tags: runtime, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere, ibmhttpserver, mobilefirst-console

We have deployed runtimes in the app server which resides in a remote RHEL system. 
We tried to connect to that mobilefirst server using ibm http server which has the default port as 8080. However, we are able to open the operations console from the ibm http server ip address, but the deployed runtimes are not visible. 
Please guide us in resolving the issue. 
Kindly help us in finding out the cause for the issue as well. 
Thanks.

```
    [8/29/16 13:21:41:310 IST] 000000c7 com.ibm.worklight.management.ui.servlet.ServiceProxy         E Received status 500 for GET http://webserveripaddress:8080/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/loginAudit
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at com.ibm.worklight.management.ui.servlet.ServiceProxy.service(ServiceProxy.java:164)
    at com.ibm.worklight.management.ui.servlet.ConsoleServicesServlet.service(ConsoleServicesServlet.java:89)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:473)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.filter.HSTSFilter.doFilter(HSTSFilter.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:978)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4845)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

[8/29/16 13:21:41:313 IST] 000000c7 com.ibm.worklight.management.ui.servlet.ServiceProxy         E Exception Connection timed out while redirecting request to http://webserveripaddress:8080/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/loginAudit
[8/29/16 13:21:41:421 IST] 000000a2 com.ibm.worklight.management.ui.servlet.ServiceProxy         E Received status 500 for GET http://webserveripaddress:8080/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes?fullInfo=true
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at com.ibm.worklight.management.ui.servlet.ServiceProxy.service(ServiceProxy.java:164)
    at com.ibm.worklight.management.ui.servlet.ConsoleServicesServlet.service(ConsoleServicesServlet.java:89)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:473)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.filter.HSTSFilter.doFilter(HSTSFilter.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:978)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4845)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

[8/29/16 13:21:41:421 IST] 000000a2 com.ibm.worklight.management.ui.servlet.ServiceProxy         E Exception Connection timed out while redirecting request to http://webserverip:8080/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes?fullInfo=true
```

Comment: Provide your server.xml and the messages.log or other log files from the application server.

Comment: What is the version of your mobilefirst server?

Comment: Version of mobilefirst server is 7.1

Comment: Please find the messages.log error file attached herewith.

Comment: @IdanAdar
Is there a difference between 80 and 8080 port?? The port set for the ibm http server is 8080.. is that correct?? Please suggest.

Comment: Looking forward to your help..

Comment: Can you verify with your network team if connections outbound from the JVM is blocked ? ie, if the JVM ( on which MFP server) were to originate an outbound connection to the webserver over non-SSL port, are the network rules set to block it out ? The error message you have printed occurs when network calls from server to webserver is blocked out

Comment: @VivinK.. Thank you for your response...

Comment: @VivinK..  We checked with the n/w team and figured out that the issue was what you have stated, please update your comment as the answer for future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you observe occurs when network calls from server to webserver is blocked out.

Management services - admin , runtime , management-ui etc communicate using REST calls and the network rules might be blocking it out.

Verify with your network team if connections outbound from the JVM is blocked.ie, if the JVM ( on which MFP server executes) were to originate an outbound connection to the webserver over non-SSL port, are the network rules set to block it out ? If so, enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Try port 10080 - this is the default port for mobilefirst 7.1 server